# Function to return an array with elements greater than an input number and an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

How do I write a function which receives an array and a number as arguments and returns a new array from the elements of the given array which are larger than the given number.

Input:

```
[10, 25, 16, -5, 30, 15, 24] , 16
```

Output:

```
[24,25,30]
```

Comment: well we advice you to give it a shot

Comment: You will have to loop over given array, check if current value is greater than provided number or not. Then maintain a list of all such elements and return it. Ta-Da!!!

Comment: [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: do you have small formule? even other problem, i will try to understand how to wirte :D

Comment: Here are links to JavaScript functions and arrays: [Functions at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions), 
[Functions at w3chools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp) and [Array at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array). You can also google search your questions and look for answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). This creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
function findGreater(arr, elem) {

  return arr.filter((item) => {
    return item > elem
  })
}



console.log(findGreater([10, 25, 16, -5, 30, 15, 24], 16))
```